# Branching Boosting Algorithms

Tags: reference-request, machine-learning, lg.learning

[Long/Servedio](http://www.phillong.info/publications/LS10_potential.pdf) showed AdaBoost/etc doesn't perform well under noisy environments, but that branching forms of boosting do.  Can any point me to a list of branching boosting algorithms, or a reference for the current best-of-breed alternatives?

Much appreciated!